# Comparing values in previous 2 columns and fill a cell with the lower value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd    
    df = pd.DataFrame({'AA': [1, 1, 2, 2], 'BB': [3, 0, -1, 3.4]})
```

Now, I need to compare the values in 'AA' and 'BB' then create and fill 'CC' column with the lower values.

I tried many ways, but without defining another function, I think there should be an effective way. What can I try next?

Answer (score 0):

Then using `min` with `axis`

```
df.min(1)
Out[263]: 
0    1.0
1    0.0
2   -1.0
3    2.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`min`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.min.html) and axis, selecting only the series you need:

```
df['CC'] = df[['AA', 'BB']].min(axis=1)
df
   AA   BB   CC
0   1  3.0  1.0
1   1  0.0  0.0
2   2 -1.0 -1.0
3   2  3.4  2.0
```